# Asathryne - A Python RPG

Tags: python, python-3.x, game

This is a project I started a while ago, and still going. It is a text-based RPG written in Python. There are two files: `asathryne.py` (the main file) and `stuff.py` (a file with some functions for programs that I make; the game imports a couple of functions from it.) Thanks for looking over it!

`asathryne.py`:

```py
from random import randint
import simplejson
import os
from jsonpickle import encode, decode
from stuff import cls, dialogue, num_input

class Character():

    def __init__(self, name, health, mana, lvl, strength, intelligence, agility, defence, weap, xp, abilities = [], inventory = [], gold = 0):

        self.name = name 
        self.health = health
        self.mana = mana
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.strength = strength
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.agility = agility
        self.defence = defence
        self.weap = weap
        self.abilities = abilities
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.gold = gold
        self.xp = xp

    def view_stats(self):

        '''Used to display data about the character to the player'''

        cls()
        print(self)
        print(f'Level {self.lvl}')
        print(f'{self.xp} xp')
        print(f'{self.gold} Gold')
        print(f'Health - {self.health}')
        print(f'Mana - {self.mana}')
        print(f'Strength - {self.strength}')
        print(f'Intelligence - {self.intelligence}')
        print(f'Agility - {self.agility}')
        print(f'Defence - {self.defence}')
        print(f'Weapon - {self.weap} ({self.weap.damage[0]}-{self.weap.damage[1]} damage)')
        print(f'Abilities - {self.abilities}')
        print(f'Inventory - {self.inventory}')
        dialogue()

    def __repr__(self):

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
class PlayerCharacter(Character):

    def __init__(self, name, class_type, health, mana, lvl, strength, intelligence, agility, defence, weap = '', abilities = [], inventory = [], gold = 0, xp = 0):

        Character.__init__(self, name, health, mana, lvl, strength, intelligence, agility, defence, weap, xp, abilities, inventory, gold)
        self.progress = {'area': '', 'king_dialogue': False, 'gates_dialogue': False, 'gates_unlocked': False}
        self.class_type = class_type
        self.abi_points = 0

    def view_stats(self):

        '''Used to display data about the player character to the player'''

        cls()
        print(self)
        print(f'Level {self.lvl} {self.class_type}')
        print(f'{self.gold} Gold')
        print(f'XP - {self.xp}/{(self.lvl + 2) ** 2}')
        print(f'{self.abi_points} ability points left')
        print(f'{self.health} Health')
        print(f'{self.mana} Mana')
        print(f'Strength - {self.strength}')
        print(f'Intelligence - {self.intelligence}')
        print(f'Agility - {self.agility}')
        print(f'Defence - {self.defence}')
        print(f'Weapon - {self.weap} ({self.weap.damage[0]}-{self.weap.damage[1]} damage)')
        print(f'Abilities - {self.abilities}')
        print(f'Inventory - {self.inventory}')
        dialogue()

    def build_char(self):

        '''Used in the beginning to build the player character'''

        while True:
            self.name = dialogue('What is your name, traveller?\n')
            if self.name != '':
                break
            else: 
                print('You must have have a name in this realm.')

        while True:
            print('Choose a class.')
            for i, c in enumerate(classes):
                print(f'{i + 1}) {c}')
            class_pick = num_input()
            cls()
            for i, c in enumerate(classes):
                if class_pick == i + 1:
                    dialogue(f'--- You chose the {c} class, which favors {c.stat}.\n')
                    setattr(self, c.stat, getattr(self, c.stat) + 3)
                    self.class_type = c
                    self.inventory.append(c.weap)
                    return
            print('--- Invalid choice')

    def equip(self, weapon):

        '''Used to equip a weapon'''

        if weapon in self.inventory:
            self.inventory.remove(weapon)
            self.weap = weapon
            dialogue(f'--- {weapon} has been equipped.')
            return True
        return False

    def item_remove(self, item):

        '''Used to remove an item from the player's inventory'''

        if item in self.inventory:
            dialogue(f'--- {item} has been removed from your inventory.\n')
            self.inventory.remove(item)
            return True
        return False

    def learn_ability(self):

        '''Used whenever the player character can learn a new ability; only used in lvl_up as of current'''

        def check_ab(abi, abl):
            for a in abl:
                if a.name == abi.name:
                    return False
            return True

        ability_list = [abi for abi in self.abilities if abi.max_lvl > abi.lvl]
        for abi in abilities: 
            for stat in ['strength', 'intelligence', 'agility', 'defence']: 
                if abi.stat == stat and getattr(self, stat) >= abi.minimum_stat:
                    if self.abilities == []:
                        ability_list.append(abi)
                    else:
                        if check_ab(abi, self.abilities):
                            ability_list.append(abi)
        if ability_list == []:
            dialogue('--- There are no avaliable abilities to learn/upgrade.\n')
            return False
        while True:
            print(f'--- You have {len(ability_list)} abilities to learn/upgrade.')
            for i, abi in enumerate(ability_list):
                print(f'{i + 1}) {abi} ({abi.lvl}/{abi.max_lvl}): {abi.desc}')
            choice = num_input()
            cls()
            if choice > len(ability_list) or choice == 0:
                print('--- Invalid choice')
                continue
            for i, abi in enumerate(ability_list):
                if choice == i + 1:
                    if abi.lvl == 0: 
                        dialogue(f'--- You have learned {abi}.\n')
                        self.abilities.append(abi)
                    else: dialogue(f'--- You have upgraded {abi}.\n')
                    abi.lvl += 1
                    self.abi_points -= 1
                    return True

    def lvl_up(self):

        '''Whenever the player's xp reaches a certain point, they will level up'''

        cls()
        while self.xp >= (self.lvl + 2) ** 2:
            self.xp -= (self.lvl + 2) ** 2
            self.lvl += 1
            self.health += 50
            self.mana += 25
            self.abi_points += 1
            dialogue(f'--- You have leveled up to level {self.lvl}! Your power increases.\n')
            points = 3
            while points > 0:
                for stat in ['strength', 'intelligence', 'agility', 'defence']:
                    current_stat = getattr(self, stat)
                    upgrade = num_input(f'--- {stat.capitalize()}: {current_stat} ({points} points remaining) Add: ')
                    if upgrade > points: upgrade = points
                    points -= upgrade
                    setattr(self, stat, current_stat + upgrade)
                    cls()
                    if points == 0: 
                        break
            while self.abi_points > 0:
                if not self.learn_ability(): 
                    break

    def save(self):

        '''Used to save player progress'''

        with open(f'{self.name}_player_data.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(encode(self))

    def combat(self, enemy):

        '''Used whenever the player enters combat'''

        self.current_health = self.health
        self.current_mana = self.mana

        enemy.current_health = enemy.health
        enemy.current_mana = enemy.mana

        dialogue(f'You encountered {enemy}!')
        your_turn = True
        while True:
            if your_turn:
                print(f'{self}\nHealth - {self.current_health}/{self.health}\nMana - {self.current_mana}/{self.mana}\n')
                print(f'{enemy}\nHealth - {enemy.current_health}/{enemy.health}\nMana - {enemy.current_mana}/{enemy.mana}\n')
                print('1) Attack')
                print('2) Pass')
                choice = num_input()
                cls()
                if choice == 1:
                    dialogue('You attack with your weapon!')
                    if randint(1, 100) < (self.agility / (self.agility + enemy.agility)) * 100:
                        damage = int(self.strength / (self.strength + enemy.defence) * randint(*self.weap.damage))
                        dialogue(f'You hit {enemy} for {damage} damage!')
                        enemy.current_health -= damage
                        if enemy.current_health <= 0:
                            win = True
                            break
                    else: 
                        dialogue('You missed!')
                elif choice == 2: 
                    dialogue('You passed.')
                else:
                    print('--- Invalid choice')
                    continue
                your_turn = False
            else:
                dialogue(f'{enemy} attacks!')
                if randint(1, 100) < (enemy.agility / (enemy.agility + self.agility)) * 100:
                    damage = int(enemy.strength / (enemy.strength + self.defence) * randint(*enemy.weap.damage))
                    if damage < 0: 
                        damage = 0
                    dialogue(f'{enemy} hit you for {damage} damage!')
                    self.current_health -= damage
                    if self.current_health <= 0:
                        win = False
                        break
                else: 
                    dialogue('It missed!')
                your_turn = True

        if win:
            dialogue(f'You defeated {enemy}, and gained {enemy.xp} xp and {enemy.gold} gold!')
            self.xp += enemy.xp
            self.gold += enemy.gold
            return True
        else:
            dialogue('You perished.')
            return False
class Class:

    def __init__(self, name, stat, weap):

        self.name = name
        self.stat = stat
        self.weap = weap

    def __repr__(self):

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
class Item:

    def __init__(self, name, value = 0, amount = 0, quest = False):

        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.amount = amount
        self.quest = quest

    def find(self, char):

        '''Used whenever the player character recieves this item'''

        char.inventory.append(self)
        dialogue(f'--- You have recieved {self} worth {self.value} gold, and it has been added to your inventory.\n')

    def __repr__(self):

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
class Weapon(Item):

    def __init__(self, name, damage, value = 0, amount = 0, quest = False):

        Item.__init__(self, name, value, amount)
        self.damage = damage
class Ability:

    def __init__(self, name, desc, stat, minimum_stat, lvl = 0, max_lvl = 3):

        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.stat = stat
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.max_lvl = max_lvl
        self.minimum_stat = minimum_stat

    def __repr__(self):

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
class Location:

    def __init__(self, name, visit_func):

        self.visit_func = visit_func
        self.name = name

    def visit(self, player):

        '''Used whenever the player visits the location'''

        dialogue(f'--- You travel to {self}.')
        self.visit_func(player)

    def __repr__(self):

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
class Area(Location):

    def __init__(self, name, locations):

        self.name = name
        self.locations = locations

    def visit(self, player):

        '''Used whenever the player visits the area'''

        player.progress['area'] = self
        dialogue(f'--- You travel to {self}.')
        while True:
            print(self)
            for i, l in enumerate(self.locations):
                print(f'{i + 1}) {l}')
            print(f'{len(self.locations) + 1}) View Character')
            print(f'{len(self.locations) + 2}) Save')
            if player.xp >= (player.lvl + 2) ** 2:
                print(f'{len(self.locations) + 3}) Level up!')
            choice = num_input()
            if choice == len(self.locations) + 1: 
                player.view_stats()
                continue
            elif choice == len(self.locations) + 2: 
                player.save()
                cls()
                print('Saved successfully!')
                continue
            elif choice == len(self.locations) + 3 and player.xp >= (player.lvl + 2) ** 2: 
                player.lvl_up()
                continue
            elif choice > len(self.locations) or choice <= 0:
                cls()
                print('--- Invalid choice')
                continue
            cls()
            self.locations[choice - 1].visit(player)
class Shop(Location):

    def __init__(self, name, stock, greeting):

        self.name = name
        self.stock = stock
        self.greeting = greeting

    def visit(self, player):

        '''Used whenever the player visits the shop'''

        dialogue(f'--- You travel to {self}.')
        dialogue(self.greeting)
        while True:
            print(f'--- You have {player.gold} gold.')
            for i, item in enumerate(self.stock):
                print(f'{i + 1}) {item} - {item.value} gold')
            print(f'{len(self.stock) + 1}) Sell items')
            print(f'{len(self.stock) + 2}) Leave')
            choice = num_input()
            cls()
            if choice == len(self.stock) + 1:
                if player.inventory == []:
                    print('--- error: inventory empty')
                    continue
                while True:
                    print(f'--- You have {player.gold} gold.')
                    choice_inv = [i for i in player.inventory if not i.quest]
                    for i, item in enumerate(choice_inv):
                        print(f'{i + 1}) {item} - {int(item.value * 0.8)} gold')
                    print(f'{len(choice_inv) + 1}) Back')
                    choice = num_input()
                    cls()
                    if choice == len(choice_inv) + 1:
                        break
                    elif choice > len(choice_inv) or choice <= 0:
                        print('--- Invalid choice')
                        continue
                    choice = choice_inv[choice - 1]
                    player.gold += int(choice.value * 0.8)
                    player.inventory.remove(choice)
                    print(f'--- You sold a {choice} for {int(choice.value * 0.8)} gold.')
                continue
            elif choice == len(self.stock) + 2: 
                return
            elif choice > len(self.stock) or choice <= 0:
                print('--- Invalid choice')
                continue
            choice = self.stock[choice - 1]
            if choice.value > player.gold:
                print('--- Insufficient funds')
                continue
            player.gold -= choice.value
            player.inventory.append(choice)
            print(f'--- You bought a {choice} for {choice.value} gold.')
class Slime(Character):

    pass

'''
character
health - How much damage the character can take before they perish
mana - Determines the character's use of abilities
lvl - Represents the character's power level
strength - Determines the amount of damage the character deals with physical attacks
intelligence - Determines the potency of the character's spells
agility - Determines the accuracy of the character's attacks, and how often they dodge attacks
defence - Determines how much damage the character take from physical attacks
abilities - list of abilities the character can use in battle
inventory - list of items the character carries
xp - how much xp gained when slain
gold - currency carried by the character
player character
class - determines what stat you favor; underdeveloped as of current
xp - Gain XP in battle; when you have enough, you will go up one level and you will get to use your skill points.
abi_points - If the player cannot learn abilities at the moment, they will recieve an ability point to use for later.
'''

king_story = (
    'Very well. Go ahead and take a seat.',
    'Now, Asathryne once was a kingdom filled with happiness and peace, ruled by Emperor Verandus.',
    'Until one day, an evil never before seen, arrived in Asathryne and tore the realm apart, leaving nothing but a barren wasteland.',
    'Sanctuary became the only thriving town left in the land.',
    'The horrid evil killed the emperor and kidnapped his daughter, our future princess. She was one of the most powerful beings in Asathryne.',
    'But this was twenty years ago. Much longer ago, when we had a fighting chance against the dark forces.',
    'We have long waited for a courageous adventurer who would be worthy enough to venture into the depths of Asathryne and rescue us from this terror.')
'''
Basically, here's how it goes:
Princess is born to emperor, and they find out she's super magical and has immense powers.
Emperor goes into deep cave. Or something. Or maybe some servant or adventerer goes. He discovers a book or something. The book contains dark magics.
The emperor reads the book and becomes corrupted with the dark magics. He hears voices telling him to summon a bunch of dark creatures.
He uses princess as a conduit to summon the army, fakes his own death, and travels to a mountain where nobody can find his daughter.
Continues summoning army until they destroy asathryne.
'''

axe = Weapon('Axe', (25, 50), 10)
staff = Weapon('Staff', (25, 30), 10)
bow = Weapon('Bow', (30, 35), 10)
sword = Weapon('Sword', (35, 40), 10)
sanctuary_key = Item('Sanctuary Key', quest = True)
pot_health = Item('Health Potion', 20)
pot_mana = Item('Mana Potion', 20)

warrior = Class('Warrior', 'strength', axe)
sorcerer = Class('Sorcerer', 'intelligence', staff)
ranger = Class('Ranger', 'agility', bow)
paladin = Class('Paladin', 'defence', sword)
classes = [warrior, sorcerer, ranger, paladin]

sanctuary_apothecary = Shop(
    name = 'Sanctuary Apothecary',
    stock = [pot_health, pot_mana],
    greeting = 'Welcome to the Apothecary! We have a variety of potions for sale. Take a look at what we have in stock.')
sanctuary_blacksmith = Shop(
    name = 'Sanctuary Blacksmith',
    stock = [axe, staff, bow, sword],
    greeting = 'Hello there, traveller! You look like you could use a reliable weapon. Step into my shop and take a look at my many wares!')

def sanctuary_gates_visit(player):
    if player.progress['gates_unlocked']:
        forest_of_mysteries.visit(player)
        return
    elif player.progress['king_dialogue']:
        dialogue('Asathryne Gatekeeper: Halt there, young - ')
        dialogue('Oh. You spoke with the King? I suppose my orders are to let you through then. Here, hand me the key.')
        while True:
            last_option = dialogue('1) Return to Sanctuary\n2) Unlock the gates\n')
            if last_option == '1':
                dialogue('Very well. Return to the town square, and come back here when you are ready.')
                return
            elif last_option == '2':
                player.item_remove(sanctuary_key)
                dialogue('--- You give the key to the gatekeeper. The gates open, revealing an expansive forest, teeming with otherworldly life.')
                dialogue('Good luck out there, traveller.')
                player.progress['gates_unlocked'] = True
                forest_of_mysteries.visit(player)
                return
            else: 
                print('--- Invalid choice')
    dialogue('Asathryne Gatekeeper: Halt there, young traveller! There is a dangerous, dark evil behind these gates. I shall not let you pass, unless you have spoken with the King of Asathryne!')
    player.progress['gates_dialogue'] = True
    while True:
        option_gate = dialogue('Type \'go\' to go meet King Brand, or \'exit\' to return to the town square.\n').lower()
        if option_gate == 'go':
            sanctuary_kings_palace.visit(player)
            return
        elif option_gate == 'exit':
            cls()
            dialogue('--- You return to the town square.')
            return
        else:
            cls()
            gate_random = randint(1, 3)
            if gate_random == 1: 
                dialogue('What are you waiting for? Go on!')
            elif gate_random == 2: 
                dialogue('Don\'t think standing here will convince me to open this gate.')
            else: 
                dialogue('Brand is waiting for you.')
sanctuary_gates = Location('Sanctuary Gates', sanctuary_gates_visit)

def sanctuary_kings_palace_visit(player):
    if player.progress['king_dialogue']:
        dialogue('King Brand: Hello, young traveller.')
        while True:
            king_story_repeat = dialogue('Do you wish to hear the story of Asathryne? (Y/N): ').lower()
            if king_story_repeat == 'y':
                for s in king_story: dialogue(s)
                return
            elif king_story_repeat == 'n':
                dialogue('Oh well, maybe for another day. Fare well, traveller!')
                return
            else:
                print('--- Invalid choice')
    dialogue(f'King Brand: At last, a brave {player.class_type} has arisen once more in this kingdom, here on a quest to save the kingdom of Asathryne from the dark evil that lies beyond the gates.')
    dialogue('Tell me young traveller, what do you seek from me?')
    while True:
        if player.progress['gates_dialogue']: 
            option_1 = dialogue('1) I\'m here to learn about Asathryne\n2) The gate keeper has sent me to meet you\n')
        else: 
            option_1 = dialogue('1) I\'m here to learn about Asathryne\n')
        if option_1 == '1':
            for s in king_story: 
                dialogue(s)
            dialogue('You will be the one to free us from this crisis.')
            dialogue('Here, take this key; you will need it to open the gate into what remains of Asathryne.')
            sanctuary_key.find(player)
            dialogue('Fare well, young traveller.')
            player.progress['king_dialogue'] = True
            return
        elif option_1 == '2' and player.progress['gates_dialogue']:
            dialogue('Ah, the gate keeper. He forbids anyone entry to the rest of Asathryne, simply because he wants to protect them.')
            break
        else:
            print('--- Invalid choice')
    while True:
        option_2 = dialogue('Let me ask you a question, traveller. Would you like to hear the Story of Asathryne? (Y/N)\n').lower()
        if option_2 == 'n':
            dialogue('Very well, very well, let me see... it\'s here somewhere... ah! The Key to Asathryne. Take this, young traveller, and good luck!')
            sanctuary_key.find(player)
            player.progress['king_dialogue'] = True
            return
        elif option_2 == 'y':
            for s in king_story:
                dialogue(s)
            dialogue('You will be the one to free us from this crisis.')
            dialogue('Here, take this key; you will need it to open the gate into what remains of Asathryne.')
            sanctuary_key.find(player)
            dialogue('Fare well, young traveller.')
            player.progress['king_dialogue'] = True
            return
        else:
            print('--- Invalid choice')
sanctuary_kings_palace = Location('Sanctuary King\'s Palace', sanctuary_kings_palace_visit)

def forest_main_visit(player):
    player.combat(Slime(
        name = 'Green Slime',
        health = 50,
        mana = 0,
        lvl = 1,
        strength = 3,
        intelligence = 0,
        agility = 2,
        defence = 2,
        weap = Weapon('Slime', (30, 40)),
        gold = randint(3, 6),
        xp = randint(2, 3)))
forest_main = Location('Forest Main', forest_main_visit)

sanctuary = Area('Sanctuary', [sanctuary_gates, sanctuary_kings_palace, sanctuary_apothecary, sanctuary_blacksmith])
forest_of_mysteries = Area('Forest of Mysteries', [sanctuary, forest_main])

stun = Ability(
    name = 'Stun',
    desc = 'You swing with your weapon, with so much force that the enemy cannot use abilities for 2 turns.',
    stat = 'strength',
    minimum_stat = 8)
fireball = Ability(
    name = 'Fireball',
    desc = 'You cast a fireball at your enemy, and on impact, it has a chance to burn the enemy.',
    stat = 'intelligence',
    minimum_stat = 8)
sure_shot = Ability(
    name = 'Sure Shot',
    desc = 'You fire a well-aimed shot from your bow, which can\'t miss, and deals critical damage.',
    stat = 'agility',
    minimum_stat = 8)
protection = Ability(
    name = 'Protection',
    desc = 'You summon a magical wall of protection, which prevents half of the damage dealt to you for 3 turns.',
    stat = 'defence',
    minimum_stat = 8)
abilities = [stun, fireball, sure_shot, protection]

def main():
    cls()
    while True:
        print('>>> Asathryne <<<')
        print('1) New game\n2) Load game')
        choice = num_input()
        cls()
        if choice == 1:
            player = PlayerCharacter(
                name = '',
                class_type = '',
                health = 50,
                mana = 25,
                lvl = 0,
                strength = 5,
                intelligence = 5,
                agility = 5,
                defence = 5,
                xp = 4,
                gold = 50)
            player.build_char()
            if dialogue('--- Type \'skip\' to skip the tutorial, or press enter to continue\n') == 'skip':
                player.equip(player.class_type.weap)
                player.lvl_up()
            else:
                dialogue(f'Welcome to The Realm of Asathryne, {player}. A kingdom filled with adventure and danger, with much in store for those brave enough to explore it. Of course, nothing a {player.class_type} such as yourself can\'t handle.')
                dialogue('Oh, of course! Allow me to introduce myself. My name is Kanron, your advisor.')
                dialogue(f'You can\'t just go wandering off into Asathryne without a weapon. Every {player.class_type} needs a {player.class_type.weap}!')
                player.equip(player.class_type.weap)
                dialogue('Before you go venturing off into the depths of this realm, you must first master some basic skills.')
                dialogue('Your stats determine your performance in battle, and the abilities you can learn.')
                dialogue('There are 4 main stats: Strength, Intelligence, Agility, and Defense.')
                while True:
                    learn_more = dialogue('Do you want to learn more about stats? (Y/N)\n').lower()
                    if learn_more == 'y':
                        dialogue('Strength increases the amount of damage you deal with physical attacks.')
                        dialogue('Intelligence increases the potency of your spells.')
                        dialogue('Agility determines the accuracy of your attacks, and how often you dodge attacks.')
                        dialogue('Defense determines how much damage you take from physical attacks.')
                        dialogue('Your mana determines your use of abilities.')
                        dialogue('Your health determines how much damage you can take before you perish.')
                        break
                    elif learn_more == 'n': 
                        break
                    else: 
                        print('--- Invalid choice')
                dialogue('Let\'s talk about your level.')
                dialogue('Your level represents how powerful you are, and determines the level of your enemies; when you go up a level, you will recieve 3 skill points to spend on any of the 4 stats, and 1 ability point to learn/upgrade abilities. Additionally, your health and mana will automatically increase.')
                dialogue('You can gain XP (experience points) in battle; when you have enough, you\'ll go up one level and get to use your skill points.')
                dialogue('Let\'s upgrade your stats. For your class, you recieve an extra 3 skill points in the stat that your class favors, and you will recieve 1 level up.')
                player.lvl_up()
                dialogue('Great job! Now that you have learned the basics, it is time you start your journey into the Realm of Asathryne.')
            sanctuary.visit(player)
        elif choice == 2:
            saves = []
            for file in os.listdir(os.fsencode(os.getcwd())):
                filename = os.fsdecode(file)
                if 'player_data' in filename: 
                    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                        saves.append(decode(file.read()))
            if saves == []:
                print('No saves found')
                continue
            while True:
                print('Choose your character.')
                for i, s in enumerate(saves):
                    print(f'{i + 1}) {s.name} - Level {s.lvl} {s.class_type}')
                choice = num_input()
                cls()
                if choice <= 0 or choice > len(saves):
                    print('--- Invalid choice')
                    continue
                player = saves[choice - 1] 
                player.progress['area'].visit(player)
        elif choice == 0 or choice > 2:
            print('--- Invalid choice')
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

`stuff.py`:

```py
import os

#a shorter version of system('cls')
def cls(): os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")

#Like input, but only accepts numbers; returns number in integer form, or 0 if the input is not a number
def num_input(string=""):
  x = input(string)
  if x.isdigit(): return int(x)
  else: return 0

#Like input, but clears after the input is taken
def dialogue(string=""):
  x = input(string)
  cls()
  return x
```

## Gameplay

The game uses presents a list of options to the player each time they can take an action; it starts out by making a new game or loading an old save. You then build your character, pick your class, and set your stats and first ability (abilities have no use yet; *possible recommendations for implementation?*). It then gives a tutorial, and puts you into the starting area, where you can progress through the story. The second area allows you to fight green slime to gain gold and xp, which you can use to buy items (also useless) and level up, respectively.

## Issues

- Some features have no use (abilities and items)
- Option lists are repeated

Anything to improve my code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `asathryne.py`

## `PlayerCharacter.learn_ability.check_ab`

This helper function can be reduced to one line:

```
def check_ab(abi, abl):
    return any(a.name == abi.name for a in abl)
```

The [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) returns `True` if any of the values passed by the iterator are true. In this case, if `aname == abi.name` results in a `True` value, then the function will return `True`. I've provided a link to the built in function if my wording was too confusing.

## Reserved variable names

[`cls`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613000/what-is-the-cls-variable-used-for-in-python-classes) is a reserved name in python. You can use it, but it's a convention to only use it to reference the first argument to class methods. I would suggest renaming that method to `clear_screen` or `clear_console`.

## Using `super`

It's more common to use [`super`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function) when calling a superclasses constructor. It makes it clear that you're referencing a super class, and you don't have to pass `self`. Have a look:

```
class Weapon(Item):

    def __init__(self, name, damage, value=0, amount=0, quest=False):

        super().__init__(name, value, amount)
        self.damage = damage
```

## Default parameter spacing

When passing or assigning default parameters, there is no space before or after the `=`. Look above for an example of that.

---

## `stuff.py`

## One line functions

Even when a function has only one line, you should still indent it. It keeps you conforming to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and makes your code style consistent.

## `num_input`

This function can be reduced to two lines:

```
def num_input(string=""):
    x = input(string)
    return int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0
```

Makes your code looks a little nicer, as has less overall code.

## Indentation

You were consistent with your indentation in your main file, but make sure that you indent **4** spaces.

Comment: Thank you; the `any()` function was helpful, but I had to replace it with `all()`, since none of the conditions can be `False`. That's why I `return False` before `True`.

Comment: @Apple Ah, I missed that. Good call. You could also use `not any(...)`.

Comment: Well, `not any()` would just be worse; if you had a list of all `False`, you would need `False` but it would return `True`; if you had a list of all `True`, you would need `True` but it would return `False`; the only case it would work is if you had a mix of both conditions, in which case it would return `False`. In other words, `all()` != `not any()`.

Comment: @Apple Wow, I didn't see it that way. I guess even as a reviewer I can still learn a thing or two!

Answer (score 3):

## isdigit()

[`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdigit#str.isdigit) does not do what you think it does. `"1²³4".isdigit()` returns `True` because all the character in the string look like digits, despite some of them being superscripts.  You want the [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdigit#str.isdecimal) function, which returns `True` if all the characters are in the set of the 10 decimal characters (ie, base-10).

## Dictionaries

You should be using dictionaries.

The character's stats, for instance, should be in `self.stat`, initialized with:

```
self.stat = { 'strength': strength,
              'intelligence': intelligence,
              'agility': agility,
              'defence': defence,
            }
```

Then opposed to writing code `getattr(self, stat)`, you would code `self.stat[stat]`.  In particular:

```
        for stat in ['strength', 'intelligence', 'agility', 'defence']: 
            if abi.stat == stat and getattr(self, stat) >= abi.minimum_stat:
```

should be coded:

```
        if self.stat[abi.stat] >= abi.minimum_stat:
```

No need to loop over all stats, looking for the correct one.  You know what the correct stat is: `abi.stat`.  Just use it.

When you do want to iterate over them, instead of:

```
            for stat in ['strength', 'intelligence', 'agility', 'defence']:
                current_stat = getattr(self, stat)
                upgrade = num_input(f'--- {stat.capitalize()}: {current_stat} ({points} points remaining) Add: ')
```

you could write:

```
            for stat in self.stat:
                current_stat = self.stat[stat]
                upgrade = num_input(f'--- {stat.capitalize()}: {current_stat} ({points} points remaining) Add: ')
```

or even:

```
            for stat, current_stat in self.stat.items():
                upgrade = num_input(f'--- {stat.capitalize()}: {current_stat} ({points} points remaining) Add: ')
```

As of Python 3.7, (and CPython 3.6 implementation) dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order, so your stats will stay in the order you expect.

---

Similarly, `self.abilities` should not be a list, it should be a dictionary.  Then instead of this code:

```
                if self.abilities == []:
                    ability_list.append(abi)
                else:
                    if check_ab(abi, self.abilities):
                        ability_list.append(abi)
```

You can get rid of the `check_ab` function, and simply have:

```
                if abi.name not in self.abilities:
                    ability_list.append(abi)
```

## Enumeration

```
        for i, abi in enumerate(ability_list):
            print(f'{i + 1}) {abi} ({abi.lvl}/{abi.max_lvl}): {abi.desc}')
        choice = num_input()
        cls()
        if choice > len(ability_list) or choice == 0:
            print('--- Invalid choice')
            continue
        for i, abi in enumerate(ability_list):
            if choice == i + 1:
```

The [`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) by default starts at zero, but it doesn't have to.  You could easily make it start at 1, eliminating the need for all those `+ 1` calculations.

```
        for i, abi in enumerate(ability_list, 1):
            print(f'{i}) {abi} ({abi.lvl}/{abi.max_lvl}): {abi.desc}')
        choice = num_input()
        cls()
        if choice > len(ability_list) or choice == 0:
            print('--- Invalid choice')
            continue
        for i, abi in enumerate(ability_list, 1):
            if choice == i:
```